# Does anyone recognize this signature

Tags: identification, art

I have this beautiful painting and I am curious who the artist is?  There is a signature on bottom rhs but I am having trouble reading it.

thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi marion glionna and welcome to History SE. Can we see the painting rather than just the signature?

Comment: Agreed, without seeing the whole painting it's very hard to identify, as image searching didn't yield any results and neither did manually searching the signature

Comment: I added picture of painting hope it helps,  thank you

Comment: @marionglionna Do you have any information regarding the time the painting was created in or its location? Reverse image searching didn't give any useful results.

Comment: **If** nobody succeeds in identifying the painting or its signature, you can always pretend that it was painted by Picasso's dog Lump (*and make a lot of money out of it ?*): https://www.nytimes.com/2006/08/26/arts/design/26lump.html

Comment: Looks kind of like something by P. Gauguin, but the signature doesn't match...

Comment: Thank you for the interest.  I do not have any other information.  I don't even remember how I got it..sorry.  I have had it for a long time.

Comment: Below the signature there appears to be an arrow pointing left. Is that of any significance? Also, are you able to check for more clues at the back of the frame, or perhaps even inside it?

Comment: there is nothing on the back.  sorry..and I also noticed the arrow but do not if it is significant or what it means

Comment: I spent more time than I should have poking around on [this website](http://www.artistssignatures.com/allsigs.php?page=1&letter=f) and gave up having barely scratched the surface. Perhaps someone else will have more luck.

Comment: Is this within scope for history.se?

Comment: @MarkCWallace It's no crazier than some of the other identification requests I've seen here.

Comment: Maybe it was the teacher of the 2nd grader that painted it.

Comment: The fact that you have this painting without there being any provenance (stamps on back, paperwork, etc.) implies that it's a painting that someone painted.  My mother has given me paintings she's painted, she signed them but I doubt anyone outside my family will know the signature.  You have a nice painting, I don't think you'll find out anything more than that.  Even if it looks like something by an established and known artist, without hard evidence, it's likely to be a copy.